# Getting all div objects from list of div's in selenium (java)

Tags: html, list, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get list of all elements using below xpath, but always getting 1 as size. Not sure what i am doing wrong here as i tried class,xpath all options. My goal is after search we get list of records and i want loop through them, i have tried several options so far but didn't had luck to get it working.

Options Tried -

```
//*[@id="wd-TemplatedList-6$62784"]
//*[@id="wd-SearchResultsPanel"]/div[3]
//*[@id="wd-SearchResultsPanel"]
//*[@id="wd-SearchResultsPanel"]/div[3]
//*[@id="wd-SearchResultsPanel"]/div[3]
//*[@id="wd-TemplatedList-6$62784"]/ul
//*[@id='wd-TemplatedList-6$62784']
//*[@id='wd-SearchResultsPanel']/div[3]
//*[@id='wd-TemplatedList-6$62784']
//*[@id='wd-TemplatedList-6$62784']/ul
//*[@id="promptOption-gwt-uid-97"]
//*[@id='wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782']
WNKQ WOLQ

/html/body/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/input
//*[@id="wd-searchInput"]/input
```

Selenium Code -

```
(driver.findElements(By.className("WNKQ WOLQ"))).size()
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='wd-TemplatedList-6$62784']/ul"));
```

HTML -

```
   <div class="WNKQ WOLQ" style="" xpath="1">
       <h3 class="WMKQ">All of Data</h3>
       <div id="wd-TemplatedList-6$62784" data-metadata-id="6$62784" class="WIAB">
          <span class="WDXV" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><button class="WOSD WPXO" data-automation-id="paginationPrevious" role="button" title="Previous" type="button" tabindex="0"><img src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/FF8AA1765E87EC5EE29C081C99FAC994.cache.svg" class="gwt-Image WHXV" alt=""></button><span class="gwt-InlineLabel WFXV" data-automation-id="paginationText"></span><button class="WOSD WPXO" data-automation-id="paginationNext" role="button" title="Next" type="button" tabindex="0"><img src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/0E3EC1EBE120F13E140528EC9B393D2A.cache.svg" class="gwt-Image WCXV" alt=""></button></span>
          <ul class="WKRQ" data-automation-id="templatedList">
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WG5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="150f41534ec84b858eb1d082b8f25a10" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$3519">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-86" data-automation-label="% zeroda Movement by Gender" title="% zeroda Movement by Gender" aria-label="% zeroda Movement by Gender" role="link" tabindex="0">% zeroda Movement by Gender</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions % zeroda Movement by Gender" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WG5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="9d38c4b55f6944f6afa6423e393e9ca2" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$3520">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-87" data-automation-label="% zeroda Movement by Race/ Ethnicity" title="% zeroda Movement by Race/ Ethnicity" aria-label="% zeroda Movement by Race/ Ethnicity" role="link" tabindex="0">% zeroda Movement by Race/ Ethnicity</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions % zeroda Movement by Race/ Ethnicity" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WF5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="7b24ce7df35f45ebaf2b34c8c6220f72" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$3447">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-88" data-automation-label="zeroda Belonging Council Members" title="zeroda Belonging Council Members" aria-label="zeroda Belonging Council Members" role="link" tabindex="0">zeroda Belonging Council Members</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions zeroda Belonging Council Members" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <span class="gwt-InlineLabel WD5F WC4F" title="A report of zerodas who are members of the zeroda Belonging Councils." id="gwt-uid-89" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">A report of zerodas who are members of the zeroda Belonging Councils.</span>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WG5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="f7e273eff015417b9d28a411307f419d" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$778">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-90" data-automation-label="zeroda Benefit Annual Rate Source" title="zeroda Benefit Annual Rate Source" aria-label="zeroda Benefit Annual Rate Source" role="link" tabindex="0">zeroda Benefit Annual Rate Source</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions zeroda Benefit Annual Rate Source" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WF5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="83e38a7853fe4651846fdb6985b772c7" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$1001">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-91" data-automation-label="zeroda Benefit Credit Report" title="zeroda Benefit Credit Report" aria-label="zeroda Benefit Credit Report" role="link" tabindex="0">zeroda Benefit Credit Report</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions zeroda Benefit Credit Report" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <span class="gwt-InlineLabel WD5F WC4F" title="Returns zerodas with Benefit Flex Credits
                      Prompts by Country.
                      Countries with Benefit Credits: USA, Canada, Singapore" id="gwt-uid-92" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">Returns zerodas with Benefit Flex Credits
                   Prompts by Country.
                   Countries with Benefit Credits: USA, Canada, Singapore</span>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WF5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="1116b283f40f4011b8142e841f964d58" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$1791">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-93" data-automation-label="zeroda Benefit Credits" title="zeroda Benefit Credits" aria-label="zeroda Benefit Credits" role="link" tabindex="0">zeroda Benefit Credits</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions zeroda Benefit Credits" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <span class="gwt-InlineLabel WD5F WC4F" title="Returns zerodas with Benefit Flex Credits
                      Prompts by Country.
                      Countries with Benefit Credits: USA, Canada, Singapore" id="gwt-uid-94" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">Returns zerodas with Benefit Flex Credits
                   Prompts by Country.
                   Countries with Benefit Credits: USA, Canada, Singapore</span>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WF5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="d14356916d4241938e7c0682074ab666" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$845">
                                        <ul class="WPEP"></ul>
                                        <div class="gwt-Label WOFP WHEP" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-95" data-automation-label="zeroda Benefit Elections - Current vs. Previous" title="zeroda Benefit Elections - Current vs. Previous" aria-label="zeroda Benefit Elections - Current vs. Previous" role="link" tabindex="0">zeroda Benefit Elections - Current vs. Previous</div>
                                        <ul class="WPEP WFFP" role="presentation">
                                           <li class="WMFP" role="presentation"><img class="gwt-Image WIWQ WJHS WDJS WPXO WAFP" src="https://zeroda.zerodacdn.com/zeroda/asset/ui-html/update/zerodaApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt="" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" data-uxi-element-id="related-actions-charm" data-uxi-element-uniqueid="true" role="button" aria-label="Related Actions zeroda Benefit Elections - Current vs. Previous" tabindex="0"></li>
                                        </ul>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <span class="gwt-InlineLabel WD5F WC4F" title="Returns all Benefit Elections for a worker, past and present. 
                      Prompts by Worker" id="gwt-uid-96" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderOne">Returns all Benefit Elections for a worker, past and present. 
                   Prompts by Worker</span>
                   <div class="wd-Text WEW2 WJW2 WIAB WA5F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" data-metadata-id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Report Definition</div>
                </div>
             </li>
             <li class="WP3F WIAB WF5F" data-automation-id="compositeContainer" role="listitem" id="wd-CompositeWidget-6$62782" data-metadata-id="6$62782">
                <div class="WA4F WO3F">
                   <div class="WOC- WGB- WIAB WPD- WND- WG4F WC4F" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553" data-metadata-id="56$284553">
                      <div class="WDD-">
                         <ul tabindex="-2" class="WPOR WCD-" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                            <li class="WDPR" role="presentation">
                               <div class="WJOR WLNR WCPR" tabindex="-2" id="86f24f58f60740698248354a940dfeab" data-automation-id="menuItem" role="presentation">
                                  <div class="WKOR">
                                     <div class="WNFP WHEP WBFP" data-automation-id="selectedItem_1422$397">
```

Comment: I didn't check all of your locators but they are only returning 1 because that's the number of elements that match. In some cases, like id=wd-SearchResultsPanel, there aren't any in the HTML you provided.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You state, "I am trying to get list of all elements", but you never indicate what elements you are looking for. Explain in words (not code or locators) what you are attempting to do, e.g. "I want to grab all sections of the page that start with 'Report Definition' and get the associated text that comes below each."

Comment: Also, `By.className("WNKQ WOLQ")` will throw an exception because you have passed in *two* class names when it's only expecting one, e.g. `By.className("WNKQ")` or `By.className("WOLQ")` are valid or if you require both, you need to change it to a CSS selector, `By.cssSelector(".WNKQ.WOLQ")`

Comment: @JeffC i am trying to Automate scenario where user searches in search bar and then gets matching results, the HTML code i shared has all those items. Now they all are in html list, i need to get count of items in that list and then loop through to match the search text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you posted an answer but there is a more efficient way to get the elements you want... it only scrapes the page once instead of twice.

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.WKRQ > li"));
```

Comment: Thanks @JeffC, agree this approach is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working, under the `<ul>` tag we have `<li>` elements, i was trying to get list from `<ul>` which was wrong approach. To solve this first i took `<ul>` data as element and then from that i pulled all the `<li>`.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("WKRQ"));
WebElement primary = elements.get(1);
List<WebElement> li_All = primary.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```